# Blender ruins model/animation when switching actions

Tags: animation, actions

Any ideas on how to fix this bug/feature of Blender? How can something so simple like selecting another action mess with my work?!

Here is the video: https://youtu.be/YE8sNfaVu6o
And the .blend file: http://www.filedropper.com/mccree28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, for the action called *TestAction.001* you can see that a *LocRotScale* track has been created, it means that, additionally to the keyframes you've created for the bones, you've created some keyframes for the whole armature in *Object* mode. And if you unfold this track you'll see that you have *Scale* keyframes as well as *Location* and *Rotation* keyframes. So delete the whole track, then, as it has changed the size of your armature when you've selected it in the Dopesheet, just select the armature and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to reset the scale.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solved it.
Still, it seams weird that scale doesn't return to normal when switching back to 'run' action, but remains small. I thought actions are completely separate. (this was behavior before deleting LocRotScale; now it all works)

Comment: it remains small because it keeps its last scale setup! i.e. the one determined by the LocRotScale keyframes. If the other animations had scale keyframes it would have come back to those new ones.